# Setting a variable equal to the data attribute of the current selected link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to set the variable current equal to the data attribute for the link which has been selected how can I do this. I know there are easier ways of doing what im trying to do but I need to do it this way.

I tried to create it but I can't do it.

```js
$(".links").click(function(){
  var current = $(this).getAttribute("data-cat");
  $(current).addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none; 
}

ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.change{
  background-color: red;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}

.print{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="hi" class="links" data-cat="print" href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="porfolio" href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="print" href="#">link3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="print">
  
</div>

<div class="porfolio">
  
</div>

<div class="print">
  
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use **[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** when you deal with `data-*` attributes :

```
var current = $(this).data("cat");
```

**NOTE :** You're missing dot `.` in your selector :

```
$('.'+current).addClass('hide');
___^
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(".links").click(function(){
  var current = $(this).data("cat");
  $('.'+current).addClass('hide');
  console.log(current);
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none; 
}

ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.change{
  background-color: red;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}

.print{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="hi" class="links" data-cat="print" href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="porfolio" href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="print" href="#">link3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="print">
  
</div>

<div class="porfolio">
  
</div>

<div class="print">
  
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).attr("data-cat");` to get the attribute and `$('.'+current).addClass('hide');` to use the variable as class selector

```js
$(".links").click(function(){
  var current = $(this).attr("data-cat");
  console.log(current)
  $('.'+current).addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none; 
}

ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.change{
  background-color: red;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}

.print{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="hi" class="links" data-cat="print" href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="porfolio" href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="print" href="#">link3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="print">
  
</div>

<div class="porfolio">
  
</div>

<div class="print">
  
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.attr()` and put a `.` in front of the cat name to create a class selector from `current` so you can target it. You could also put a `.` at the beginning of the `data-cat` values in your HTML.

```js
$(".links").click(function(){
  var current = $(this).attr("data-cat");
  $('.' + current).addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none; 
}

ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.change{
  background-color: red;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}

.print{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="hi" class="links" data-cat="print" href="#">link1</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="porfolio" href="#">link2</a></li>
  <li><a class="links" data-cat="print" href="#">link3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="print">
  
</div>

<div class="porfolio">
  
</div>

<div class="print">
  
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```